unknown database backup file extension *.gbk
I have a database backup from an old desktop application, and the backup file has the extension *.gbk. Could you please help me identify which database uses this extension?

It cloud be InterBase or Firebird.

It is Firebird or Interbase.  The database generally has an extension of .gdb or .fdb and the backup is generally .gbk
From Destructor.de

GBAK Firebird Backup and Restore
For backups,  is the database (= database string) you want to back up,  is the path and file name of the backup file. The usual extension for the backup file is .fbk for Firebird and .gbk for InterBase. Only SYSDBA or the database owner can perform a backup.

Although we always used .gbk for firebird as well.
